# How to suppress excel pivot error - "We can't drill down here."

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2013

I've got a pivot table using data from two tables related together - Excel 2013 Data model.

I'm gettin an error "***We can't drill down here.***" while double-clicking on a first column items in a pivot.

My goal is to execute macro (which will btw increase one value in a pivot and refresh pivot) when user double-clicks on a first column item. I just can't suppress the error message after the double-click. I tried to swich Application.DisplayAlerts property to False, but I'm still getting the error.

Any idea how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `BeforeDoubleClick` event, add the line: `Cancel = True`.

Comment: You're quite welcome!  Just for future reference, you cannot stop messages that result from user actions only those that are initiated by code.